# Creating a recursive function that gets the sum of all possible subsets in a list of integers

Tags: python, recursion

If i were to get the sum of all possible subset-combinations in the list [1,2,3] i would use the code below:

```
def f():
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            for k in range(2):
                    x = i*1 + j*2 + k*3 
                    print x
f()
```

How can i make a recursive function that does this for any list?
I can solve this using itertools.combinations but i would like to learn the recursive way.
Thanks

Comment: All possible combinations of the list `[1, 2, 3]` is just `[[1, 2, 3]]`. Or did you want all possible subset-combinations of all lengths 0 through 3?

Comment: all possible subset combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def allsums(a):
  x = a[0]
  if len(a) > 1:
    yy = allsums(a[1:])
    return set(x + y for y in yy).union(yy)
  else:
    return set([0, x])
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's write a recursive function to output all combinations of all subsets of a list.

For a given list, the combinations are the the list itself, plus all combinations of the list minus each member. That's easy to translate straight to Python:

```
def combinations(seq):
    yield seq
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        for combination in combinations(seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]):
            yield combination
```

However, this will obviously yield duplicates. For example, the list `[1, 2, 3]` contains both `[1, 2]` and `[1, 3]`, and they both contain `[1]`. So, how do you eliminate those duplicates? Simple, just tell each sub-list how many elements to skip:

```
def combinations(seq, toskip=0):
    yield seq
    for i in range(toskip, len(seq)):
        for combination in combinations(seq[:i] + seq[i+1:], i):
            yield combination
```

---

Now, you want to sum all combinations? That's easy:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> map(sum, combinations(a))
[6, 5, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3]
```